# Am I calling my controller function (vb.net) from my AngularJS code correctly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, angularjs

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, and I'm not too sure if my NewTextFile Sub is being called properly. What this method does is it simply creates a textfile on my local server. As a fellow newbie I appreciate you taking a look. Thank you.

```
function TableController($scope) {
    $scope.requests = [];

    $scope.addCertificate = function () {
        var certificate = {
            emailAddress: $scope.emailAddress,
            certificateType: $scope.certificateType,
            searchType: $scope.searchType,
            submittedNumbers: $scope.submittedNumbers,
        };

        $scope.requests.push(certificate);
    };

    $scope.removeCertificate = function (index) {
        $scope.requests.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.requestThatCertificatesBeEmailed = function () {
        for (index = 0; index < $scope.requests.length; ++index) {
            alert('For loop entered, hello!')
            var submittedEmailAddressString = $scope.requests[index].emailAddress;
            var submittedCertificateTypeString = $scope.requests[index].certificateType;
            var submittedSearchTypeString = $scope.requests[index].searchType;
            var submittedSearchString = $scope.requests[index].submittedNumbers;

            alert(submittedSearchTypeString);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Controllers/CreateTextFile/NewTextFile',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    submittedEmailAddress: submittedEmailAddressString,
                    submittedCertificateType: submittedCertificateTypeString,
                    submittedSearchType: submittedSearchTypeString,
                    submittedSearch: submittedSearchString
                }),
                processData: false,
                dataType: 'json'
            });
            alert('Succesfully submitted request')
        }
    };
}
```

Here is my vb.net controller class:

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security

Public Class CreateTextFileController

    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    <HttpPost> _
    <NonAction()> _
    Private Sub NewTextFile(submittedEmailAddress As String, submittedCertificateType As String, submittedSearchType As String, submittedSearch As String)

    //Create Textfile on local server here given the input parameters

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Dont use jQuery's AJAX with Angular, use `$http`

Comment: In the URL don't use the controllers prefix.  Just the controller and action asssuming that is how your routing is configured (You could hit it with controller/action in a browser) (default).

Comment: I'm new to all this so I have no clue what I am doing, but my CreateTextFileController Class is in my folder called "Controllers." Then the method I want to call is NewTextFile. I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0):

I think, judging from the url you are calling in your angularjs file, that the key ingredient you are missing is called "routing". Here are some helpful links:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing

In short, "routing" is the term MVC uses to describe "associate a url with a controller method". Your angular file that does:

`$.ajax({
   url: '/Controllers/CreateTextFile/NewTextFile',
   ...`

is not going to do what you want because routing abstracts the url from the filepath. You are instead using the filepath and the method name as the url, which is not necessarily going to be the case. Routing is very powerful, you can have multiple urls map to one method, or one method map to multiple urls with various patterns and once you get the hang of it, you'll wonder what you ever did without it.

Also, you should heed the comment that says to use the `$http` angular module to do ajax requests intead of JQuery, since it is better integrated with the angularjs framework.